# Need to pick contact from a dialog preference

Tags: android

I would like to add a preference setting that uses an `ACTION_PICK` intent. My goal is to acquire the phone number of a contact in my phone by using a preference. Is this possible?

I can run this code from my activity but I discovered I cannot run it from a class that extends `DialogPreference`.

```
Intent intentContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI); 
startActivityForResult(intentContact, PICK_CONTACT);
```

Or is there a way to start a new `Activity` from a `Preference`? Then that `Activity` could execute the above two lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

```
    // Get Custom contact Pref
    Preference customContact = (Preference)findPreference("custom_contact");
    customContact.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, PICK_CONTACT);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: and how do I get the chosen contact's phone number?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the contact preference as "Preference ..." in preferences.xml, if you use "EditTextPreference..." the text edit dialog is shown, and this is not convenient in this case.